# Copy values between pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, lambda

I spent a good deal of yesterday trying to copy the values in one column (columnA) of a pandas dataframe to another column (columnB) in the same dataframe. The columns are floats with numeric and NaN values.

I researched this site, Stack Overflow, Google, etc., and everything I tried either failed, did nothing, and/or gave me a SettingWithCopyWarning warning. The two methods below both work as far as copying values, but both give this warning.

If it makes a difference, columnA comes from a read_csv operation, while columnB is inserted later.

Basically, I'd like some feedback on which way is better, or if there's a way to accomplish this so that the warning isn't triggered.

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    df['columnB'] = df['columnA']

df['columnB'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['columnA'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at this closely.

First, let's create a 5x5 dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5,-1), index=[*'abcde'], columns=[*'ABCDE'])
df
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D   E  
a   0   1   2   3   4  
b   5   6   7   8   9 
c  10  11  12  13  14 
d  15  16  17  18  19 
e  20  21  22  23  24
```

Let's create a new column from a old:

```
df['Z'] = df['A']
df
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   Z
a   0   1   2   3   4   0
b   5   6   7   8   9   5
c  10  11  12  13  14  10
d  15  16  17  18  19  15
e  20  21  22  23  24  20
```

> Note: no SettingWithCopyWarnings

Now, let's take a copy of df calling it df_1, and change a cell in df_1 what happens to df?:

```
df_1 = df
df_1.loc['a','A'] = 100
print(df_1)
print('\n')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     A   B   C   D   E   Z
a  100   1   2   3   4   0
b    5   6   7   8   9   5
c   10  11  12  13  14  10
d   15  16  17  18  19  15
e   20  21  22  23  24  20

     A   B   C   D   E   Z
a  100   1   2   3   4   0
b    5   6   7   8   9   5
c   10  11  12  13  14  10
d   15  16  17  18  19  15
e   20  21  22  23  24  20
```

Note: df also changed!

Now, let's take a subset of df, calling it df_ac:

```
 df_ac = df['a':'c']
 df_ac
```

Output:

```
     A   B   C   D   E   Z
a  100   1   2   3   4   0
b    5   6   7   8   9   5
c   10  11  12  13  14  10
```

Let's change a value in df_ac and see what happens:

```
df_ac['X'] = df['B']
```

First, we get the SettingWithCopyWarning.  What does this mean?  Well, it means that in this case df didn't get changed.

```
df_ac
```

Output:

```
     A    B   C   D   E   Z    X
a  100    1   2   3   4   0    1
b    5    6   7   8   9   5    6
c   10   11  12  13  14  10   11
```

However, print df,

```
     A    B   C   D   E   Z
a  100    1   2   3   4   0
b    5    6   7   8   9   5
c   10   11  12  13  14  10
d   15   16  17  18  19  15
e   20   21  22  23  24  20
```

One way to avoid this warning is to use `copy'

```
df_ac = df['a':'c'].copy()
df_ac['X'] = df_ac['B']
```

No, SettingWithCopyWarning.

Comment: Great explanation! It led me to figure it out.My dataframe df was a copy of one called data - `df = data.loc[data['columnC'] == X]`, rather than just using df from the start - `df = df.loc[df['columnC'] == X]`

Comment: Thank you, @recurvata.  Happy coding.